# how to change kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a rocky Linux 9.2 and it has kernel version 5.14,
I want to change this kernel to version 4.
Can I do it?

Thanks Regards

I have a dongle Bluetooth and there has a bug in kernel and no show device.
also I tried installing vmware and again bug.

Comment: In general, no.  A given distribution usually supports a small range of kernels, but you're talking about a giant step backwards.  You would have to move back to RHEL 8 to get a version 4 kernel.

Comment: @TimRoberts Why not? `A given distribution usually supports a small range of kernels` I strongly disagree - as linux kernel is so separate from anything else, you can boot pretty much from anything, and kernel is and has been designed specifically to work like that for decades. Only the recent (bug? feature?) in glibc 2.33 made it incompatible with kernel<4.4. Still, with kernel>=4.4 you are fine with any "given distribution" with glibc>2.33, and with glibc<2.33 you are fine with anything

Comment: Hasn't been my experience.  Too many assumptions get violated.

Comment: RH backports so much that their kernel versions are meaningless. If you are trying to run some out-of-tree Realtek driver then you might try running the latest Fedora kernel, which likely supports your dongle.

Answer (score 1):

> how to change kernel?

Consists of 3 steps:

- get compiled kernel

  - either compile a kernel, i.e. install compiler and all the tools needed, download kernel source from kernel.org, and compile.
  - Or download a compiled kernel for your distribution, for example by downgrading your distribution or manually downloading an old RPM package of the kernel and dealing with incompatibilities
- install kernel

  - either install it with RPM or your package manager
  - or copy the files manually to needed location - somewhere in /boot and /usr/lib/modules
  - or when compiling from source there is `make modules_install` etc.
- boot from it

  - configure your boot manager that you using - grub, systemd-efi, or other - with a new entry to see the new kernel file and initrd
  - and then boot from it.

Good luck.